# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toastr')

Tags: angular

I want to show `toastr` during error handling:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, from } from 'rxjs';
import { ToastrService } from "ngx-toastr";

import { JsonError } from './../core/models/json-error';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ErrorService {
    constructor(private toastr: ToastrService) { }

    handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<JsonError> {
        this.toastr.success('1', '2');
        ...
    }
}
```

using:

```
...
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AccountService {
    private getUserProfileUrl = 'api/account/profile';

    constructor(private http: HttpClient,
        private errorService: ErrorService) { }

    getUserProfile(): Observable<Json | JsonError> {
        return this.http
            .get<Json | JsonError>(this.getUserProfileUrl)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.errorService.handleError)
            );
    }
}
```

But there is error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toastr')`

Also I've added `ErrorSErvice` into `providers` of `AppModule` and added `ToastrModule.forRoot()` into `AppModule` `imports` but the same issue.

What's wrong here?